# Using C# WinForms, how do you modify system audio output, ie for equalizing audio?

Tags: c#, winforms, audio

I would like to write a C# winforms app to control the EQ of my system sound output. I have found ways to manipulate specific sources of audio, such as the microphone or playing a specific mp3 file, but would like the equalizer to be able to modify the system output generally.

How do you access the system audio output and manipulate it before it hits the speakers?

Answer (score 0):

That is dependent on your audio drivers. Only some drivers integrate EQ control into Windows audio settings. Others use a custom control panel (like DTS Sound Control). I don't think there is a reliable solution to directly access the EQ settings.

Comment: But you can use a library like CSCore to manipulate the equalization of a specific sound source (like an mp3). I'm just trying to find the source for system audio and do something (anything) to it before it hits the speakers)